# Avro vs Protobuf Performance

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers, performance-testing, avro

I wrote a JMH benchmark to compare the serialization performance of Avro (1.8.2) & Protobuf (3.5.0) in java 1.8. According to JMH, Protobuf can serialize some data 4.7 million times in a second where as Avro can only do 800k per second.

The test data that was serialized is around 200 bytes and I generated schema for both Avro and Protobuf.

Here is my Avro serialization code, can someone familiar with Avro ensure that I haven't made some cardinal mistake?

The method called serialize is what JMH benchmarked. Also, I have posted this at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/skmE78F-XbE

Many Thanks

```
public final class AvroSerialization{

    private BinartEncoder encoder;
    private final SpecificDatumWriter writer;

    public AvroSerialization( ){
         this.writer = new SpecificDatumWriter( AvroGeneratedClass.class );
    }

    //MyDataObject = A pojo that contains the data to be serialized
    public final byte[] serialize( MyDataObject data ){

         ByteArrayOutputStream  out = new ByteArrayOutputStream( 1024 );
         encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder( out, encoder );

         AvroGeneratedClass avroData = createAvro( data );

         writer.write( avroData, encoder );
         encoder.flush();

         return out.toByteArray();

    }

    //AvroGeneratedClass = Class generated by the Avro Schema
    public final static AvroGeneratedClass createAvro( MyDataObject data ){
         AvroGeneratedClass  avroData = AvroGeneratedClass.newBuilder()
         .setXXX( data.getXXX )
         .setXXX( data.getXXX )
         ... 
         return avroData;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, could you share the protobuff code? i am interested in replicating this benchmark. And the avsc schema file too.

Answer (score -2):

AVRO always serialize data with its schema.

In the protobuf approach the server assumes the client already knows the schema so it just serialize the data to binary format.

For transactional workloads protobuf is usually better.

AVRO is usually better for analytical workloads where you need to serialize a huge amount of records. In this case, the schema serialization is often negligible and AVRO serialization is slightly more compact.

Comment: Note that Avro has schemaless mode as well, where it will serialise only the binary data and assume that the consumer has access to the schema (represented as JSON) when deserialising.

Comment: This is not correct. AVRO can be used for transactional data as well, without embedding the schema with the data. An example is the whole Kafka ecosystem with the Schema Registry