# Moving from caffeine to redisson redis with AWS elatic cache CPU increase

Tags: redis, redisson, caffeine-cache

We are moving an in-memory cache implementation of DB results cache to redis(Aws elastic cache). The JVM memory usage for the redisson based redis implementaion in performance test show more CPU usage (about 30 to 50%[image]

The blue line is the redisson to redis implementation of distributed cache and the yellow line is the in memory caffeine implementation. Is this expected legitimate increase due to more I/O ? Or some redission configuration tuning needed?

Comment: Redission has [native support](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/7.-distributed-collections/#local-cache) for Caffeine if you want the best of both. The docs say this uses a pubsub channel for invalidations, offering a near cache that is 45x faster. But yes, a remote cache does incur overhead and most often requires tuning your serialization choice (e.g. preferring protobuf, never using native serialization). Doordash [found](https://doordash.engineering/2022/05/03/how-we-applied-client-side-caching/) they needed a local cache in front of redis to achieve their performance objectives.

Comment: Thanks for the input @BenManes! We do use avro format for serialization. Does protobuf excel more at serialization cost from your experiences?

Comment: It has been a very long time; originally Avro had very poor performance (maybe 10yrs ago). I don't know anymore, except that in those days protobuf was a top performer. I am sure things have changed a lot since and hopefully it is quite competitive.

Comment: This [2018 thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361262/avro-vs-protobuf-performance) says someone observed 6x higher throughput for protobuf. You would probably be best served writing a benchmark for your data, though.